# Is it safe to declare dependent javascript variables in the same statement?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Currently, I write something like this to assign dependent variables:

```
var x = 10; var y = x * 3;
```

However, I would like to keep the code shorter with writing this:

```
var x = 10, y = x * 3;
```

I already know that it works in the current Chrome. But my question is: **is it safe to use, and does it ALWAYS work in EVERY browser?**

I did not find any documentation on whether the script is SUPPOSED to always know the value of `x` in the second assignment `y = x * 3`, because both assignments are within the SAME statement (separated by the `,`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. It's formalized in [the ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.io/#x12.2) that all JavaScript engines follow :

[image]

And the evaluation order must be from left to right :

[image]

The only problem is the impact this frequently has on readability.

A common formatting is

```
var x = 10,
    y = x * 3;
```

Comment: Thank you! First it was not clear that the evaluation order part is a quotation. But since it stands in the ECMA document, this answers my question.

Comment: Only the recent browsers follow this standard but it's probably the same for the older standard too in this matter

Comment: @Esailija I linked to the ES5 spec because I don't have a link to a browser friendly version of ES3 (that is, no PDF or... doc). Do you have one ?